# Unable to get token from Thinktecture Authorization Server

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model, thinktecture

I am unable to get an access token from Thinktecture Authorization Server. After successfully getting grant code, I try make a POST request to the token endpoint, but always get a 400 Bad Request with this response:
*message: "{ "error": "invalid_client" }"*

My request was:
POST to https://host/authz/users/oauth/token
request body:
*{"code":"grant_code_received_from_previous_request","client_id":"myclient","grant_type":"authorization_code","client_secret":"mysecret"}*

My client is setup properly in the Authorization Server. My client id and secret are correct; they are the same value I used to the grant code in the previous request (/users/oauth/authorize).

Any idea for this "invalid_client" issue? There is no other information in the response other than "invalid_client".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to send client credentials using http basic authentication instead of posting Id and secret in the body.

Comment: Hi Dominic I added the basic authz in the header , I am also using the Advanced rest client extension.But still getting the invalid_client . Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I followed @leastprivilege advice and did that:

```
// set up the base64-encoded credentials
let clientId = "myclientid"
let clientSecret = "myclientsecret"

let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", clientId, clientSecret)
let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))
```

After that created the request instance like this:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// Only these four are required based on the documentation.        
let postString = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=\(code)&redirect_uri=app:/your.redirect.uri"

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can get the more information on the logging file. 
Take a look at it, you can check the logging options on the web.config of the Identity Server:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
<!-- simple system.diagnostics logger -->
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
    <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Trace.log" />
    <remove name="Default" />
  </listeners>
</trace>

<!-- can be used with TraceSource logger -->
<!--<sources>
  <source name="Thinktecture.IdentityServer"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData= "trace.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>-->
```

More information about logging at:
http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/configuration/logging.html